# Boost bootstrap throwing errors

Tags: c++, batch-file, boost, mingw

Premise: I'm new to this. Anyway, I'm trying to bootstrap the boost library through the command `bootstrap.bat mingw`. As you guessed, I'm on windows 64-bit and using the MinGW toolchain. But when I run the command, the output is

```
Building Boost.Build engine
builtins.cpp: In function 'FILE* windows_popen_wrapper(const char*, const char*)':
builtins.cpp:2483:18: error: '_popen' was not declared in this scope; did you mean '_lopen'?
 2483 |         result = _popen( command, "r" );
      |                  ^~~~~~
      |                  _lopen
builtins.cpp: In function 'LIST* builtin_shell(FRAME*, int)':
builtins.cpp:2418:20: error: '_pclose' was not declared in this scope; did you mean '_lclose'?
 2418 |     #define pclose _pclose
      |                    ^~~~~~~
builtins.cpp:2549:19: note: in expansion of macro 'pclose'
 2549 |     exit_status = pclose( p );
      |                   ^~~~~~
debugger.cpp: In function 'char* debug_string_read(FILE*)':
debugger.cpp:110:14: error: 'strdup' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'strcmp'?
  110 |     result = strdup( buf->value );
      |              ^~~~~~
      |              strcmp
debugger.cpp: In function 'void debug_init_handles(const char*, const char*)':
debugger.cpp:1073:21: error: '_fdopen' was not declared in this scope; did you mean '_wsopen'?
 1073 |     command_input = _fdopen( read_fd, "r" );
      |                     ^~~~~~~
      |                     _wsopen
debugger.cpp: In function 'void init_parent_handles(HANDLE, HANDLE)':
debugger.cpp:1091:21: error: '_fdopen' was not declared in this scope; did you mean '_wsopen'?
 1091 |     command_child = _fdopen( _open_osfhandle( (intptr_t)in, _O_RDONLY ), "r" );
      |                     ^~~~~~~
      |                     _wsopen
execnt.cpp: In function 'int is_parent_child(DWORD, DWORD)':
execnt.cpp:1085:23: error: 'stricmp' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'strncmp'?
 1085 |                 if ( !stricmp( pinfo.szExeFile, "csrss.exe" ) &&
      |                       ^~~~~~~
      |                       strncmp
execnt.cpp:1088:23: error: 'stricmp' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'strncmp'?
 1088 |                 if ( !stricmp( pinfo.szExeFile, "smss.exe" ) &&
      |                       ^~~~~~~
      |                       strncmp
jam.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**, char**)':
jam.cpp:200:22: error: 'environ' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'union'?
  200 | # define use_environ environ
      |                      ^~~~~~~
jam.cpp:561:37: note: in expansion of macro 'use_environ'
  561 |         var_defines( root_module(), use_environ, 1 );
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
jam.cpp: In function 'char* executable_path(const char*)':
jam.cpp:729:54: error: 'strdup' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'strcmp'?
  729 |     return ( !ret || ret == sizeof( buf ) ) ? NULL : strdup( buf );
      |                                                      ^~~~~~
      |                                                      strcmp
sysinfo.cpp: In function 'unsigned int {anonymous}::std_thread_hardware_concurrency()':
sysinfo.cpp:93:21: error: 'std::thread' has not been declared
   93 |         return std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
      |                     ^~~~~~
File Not Found

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
Please consult bootstrap.log for further diagnostics.
```

Contents of bootstrap.log:

'###
'###Using 'mingw' toolset.
'###

C:\Users\lenerdv\Desktop\cpp\training\lib\boost_1_72_0\tools\build\src\engine>g++ -x c++ -std=c++11 -s -O3 -o b2.exe   -DNDEBUG  builtins.cpp class.cpp command.cpp compile.cpp constants.cpp cwd.cpp debug.cpp debugger.cpp execcmd.cpp execnt.cpp filent.cpp filesys.cpp frames.cpp function.cpp glob.cpp hash.cpp hcache.cpp hdrmacro.cpp headers.cpp jam.cpp jambase.cpp jamgram.cpp lists.cpp make.cpp make1.cpp md5.cpp mem.cpp modules.cpp native.cpp object.cpp option.cpp output.cpp parse.cpp pathnt.cpp pathsys.cpp regexp.cpp rules.cpp scan.cpp search.cpp strings.cpp subst.cpp sysinfo.cpp timestamp.cpp variable.cpp w32_getreg.cpp modules/order.cpp modules/path.cpp modules/property-set.cpp modules/regex.cpp modules/sequence.cpp modules/set.cpp

C:\Users\lenerdv\Desktop\cpp\training\lib\boost_1_72_0\tools\build\src\engine>dir *.exe
 
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 727E-472A

Directory of C:\Users\lenerdv\Desktop\cpp\training\lib\boost_1_72_0\tools\build\src\engine

C:\Users\lenerdv\Desktop\cpp\training\lib\boost_1_72_0\tools\build\src\engine>copy /b .\b2.exe .\bjam.exe
The system cannot find the file specified.

BTW, I'm following [this tutorial](https://andres.jaimes.net/718/how-to-install-the-c-boost-libraries-on-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

Download MinGW_w64 instead.

Looks like support for MinGW has dropped while boost has continued active. For latest versions of boost use MinGW_w64.

I removed MinGW path and added a new MinGW_64 containing the files from https://winlibs.com/#download-release in `C:\MinGW_64` and added to `PATH`. Could build the `b2.exe` afterwards.